# Replacement pattern for one value of a multivalue field in views

Tags: views, tokens

Rewriting the results of a views field, I wonder if there is a way to use a replacement pattern for the first, second and third value of a multivalue field.

In my case, as example:

I have tried to use this rewritten tags field:
   [field_tagging:0]
   [field_tagging:1]
   [field_tagging:2]

However, this is not rewritten/recognized as replacement patterns.

The result I need, is that in the views field has three tag links, which have a rewritten path (in this case it also uses !1 for the contextual value in the URL)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, although not exactly the same.  Here's what worked for me:
 1. Enable the module entity_token which is a sub-module of Entity.
 2. Use field-tagging:0 (with a dash not an underscore).  Depending on exactly what you are trying to do, you may need a further parameter such as field-tagging:0:url.

It seems that field_tagging and field-tagging are two different things.  The first one doesn't accept :0.